# How to use deferRender in AngularJS datatable?

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, web-services

I have tried this code.

**HTML Code**

```
<table id="example" data-datatable="ng">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S.No</th>
      <th>Menu Name</th>
      <th>Menu Link</th>
      <th>Menu Path</th>
      <th>Icon</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="x in names">
      <td>{{x.iMenu_id}}</td>
      <td>{{x.cMenu_Name}}</td>
      <td>{{x.cLink}}</td>
      <td>{{x.cHelpLink}}</td>
      <td>{{x.cCss_Class}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Script Code**

I am using this function to getting the data from the web services.

```
(function (angular) {
        ' ';
        angular.module('AngularApp', ['datatables'])
            .controller('AngularCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.get("AngularJS.asmx/Page_Select")
                    .then(function (response) {
                        $scope.names = response.data.Table;
                        deferRender = true;
                    });
            }])
    })(window.angular);
```

**Web Service(C#) code**

```
        public class HelloWorldData
        {
            public String Message;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public void Page_Select()
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Clear();
            Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            HelloWorldData data = new HelloWorldData();
            string sql = "Exec PB_GetMasterDetails @opt=20";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BB_CONSTR"]);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
        }
```

**Output** 
I'm getting this output in web service.

```
{
  "Table": [
    {
      "iMenu_id": 10,
      "cMenu_Name": "BIRTH REGISTER1",
      "cLink": "/Ward/NewIPPatSearch.aspx",
      "cHelpLink": "Help/About us/aboutaosta.html",
      "cCss_Class": "icon-home"
    },
    {
      "iMenu_id": 14,
      "cMenu_Name": "CHANGE PASSWORD",
      "cLink": "/UserAdmin/tchangepwd.aspx",
      "cHelpLink": "Help/About us/aboutaosta.html",
      "cCss_Class": "icon-home"
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    {
      "iMenu_id": 2500,
      "cMenu_Name": "CITY1",
      "cLink": "/Masters/mCity.aspx",
      "cHelpLink": "Help/About us/aboutaosta.html",
      "cCss_Class": "icon-home"
    }
  ]
}
```

This method is working for me, but it takes quite some time to load the data. So I have tried deferRender method but it's not working for me. Does someone know another solution?

Comment: *It takes time* .... can vary from 2 seconds to 10 years. Did you measure that ? Which part is taking time, executing the procedure or serializing to Json ? Maybe both ? How many items are you returning ? Is that a remote server ? Edit your question and provide these information.

Comment: Local server... It's take 5-6 seconds to load the data's... loading tome is taken by web service.

Comment: If you execute the procedure on the database directly, how much time does it take ?

Comment: it's taking 1 or 2 sec..

Comment: Why are you retrieving `2016` record only to show 10 of them. Shouldn't you be retrieving 10 at a time (Paging) for a better performance ?

Answer (score 0):

you should try profiling where is your bottleneck...
here are some options I can think of:

1.1 time to process the WebRequest (Your Database Fetch)
 A1 - optimize the database schema or other optimizations

1.2 time to transfer the response data to the client
  A1 - you can compress your data.
  A2 - you can paginate your data to smaller groups (~100 records), that way   the user will load some data and after a short while will get more data until all 2000+ records received.

1.3 time to process the data client side.
  A1 - Seems legit, I don't see anything that should slow down, but i ain't an Angular Ninja.